# Internet Explorer 7 on Windows XP - degraded JS support?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, windows-xp

Our webapp uses lots of JQuery, and was tested in IE7+, FF, Chrome - all worked fine - on our Windows 7 computers. But when the site went live complains poured in - turns out majority of our users still sit on Windows XP (their work machines, unlikely to update in the near future).

As we found out, IE7 + Win7 != IE7 + WinXP. The functionality of all the JQuery goodness on IE7+XP is almost as bad as on IE6.

So I am scrambling for solutions. Is there any documentation regarding the differences in the JS and CSS engines of IE7 on WinXP vs Win7? Is there any sane way to gracefully reduce JS functionality based on what browser *and* OS version the user has?

Edit: IE8 and IE9 do not have any problems. As to compatibility modes, I see this in some of our pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

But on a page with the most sophisticated JQuery features (which break in the most fantasmagorical way) there is actually no such tag at all.

Comment: This is the sort of problem that makes me shiver.

Comment: Did you sort out the problem? I have hammered into the same. XP + IE not working with jquery.

Comment: Our GUI devs ended up creating a separate modified css file for IE. No one-size-fits-all solution unfortunately.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using and what types of errors are being generated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compatibility issues with IE7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178522/compatibility-issues-with-ie7)